# Adding a tag to a filter when you were on a page that doesn't exist in the new filter causes no results found error

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

I have  found an issue where the following error appears when creating a new filter, even though results do exist:

> That's a miss
>
> Sorry, that filter combination has no results.
> Please try different criteria.

To reproduce:

1. Click on a tab with a lot of entries. For instance, "active"
2. Look at the last page. At the moment, the last page for "active" is 714862.
3. Add a tag to the filter, for instance, [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), which makes the filter smaller than the last one.
4. Note that the error message above appears claiming that the filter has no results. This is not true, as there are results.

This error does not appear if you start on a page common to both filters, such as page 1.

The error seems to happen because page 714862 does not exist in the new filter (active + [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) only goes up to page 65412 as of this writing).

The solution would be to either:

- Move the user to Page 1 of the new filter
- Move the user to the last page of the new filter

Keeping them on a non-existent page and then claiming there are no results is a problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed and it will be deployed in `rev 2015.12.17.3996` (meta) and `rev 2015.12.17.3103` (main).

The user will now be changed to page 1 if the paging is affected by their filter choice (e.g. changing sort/filter/tags, etc.)